# Measurability of $A \subset B \subset \mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If  $A \subseteq B \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ and B is measurable with $ m(B)=0 $ then A is measurable with $ m(A)=0$ .

I'm trying to see that if $m^∗(X)=m^∗(X∩B)+m^∗(X∩B^c)$ than A is measurable. But what I know is that $X∩A⊆X∩B$ and measure is monotone. On the other side I know that $X∩B^c⊆X∩A^c$ But I'm stuck.

Comment: what's your working definition of measurable?

Comment: The definition I am working with is $m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \cap E^c) $

Comment: I'm trying to see that if $m^*(X) = m^*(X \cap B ) + m^*(X \cap B^c) $ than A is measurable. But what I know is that $X \cap A\subseteq X \cap B $ and measure is monotone. On the other side I know that $ X \cap B^c \subseteq X \cap A^c $ 

But I'm stuck.

Comment: Deni, you could include this in the body of the question in order to avoid votes for closure.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is to prove the measurability of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use the definition that a set $S$ is measurable if and only if for any $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $m^*(E) = m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A^c \cap E)$, for the outer measure $m^*$.

Let $E$ be a subset of the reals. Since $m^*$ is subadditive, we need only show that $m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A^c \cap E)$ is less than $m^*(E)$.

But since $m^*$ is monotone, $m^*(A^c \cap E) \leq m^*(E),$ and $m^*(A \cap E) \leq m^*(B) = 0.$ Therefore
$$
m^*(E) \leq m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A^c \cap E) \leq 0 + m^*(E),
$$
so we must have the desired equality. We conclude that $A$ is measurable. Once again, since $m^*$ is monotone $m^*(A) \leq m^*(B) = 0$, so $A$ also has the desired measure.

Answer (score 1):

If $m:\wp\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\rightarrow\left[0,\infty\right]$
denotes an outer measure then $B$ is measurable if $$m\left(X\right)=m\left(X\cap B\right)+m\left(X\cap B^{c}\right)$$
for each $X\in\wp\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$. Actually $$m\left(X\right)\geq m\left(X\cap B\right)+m\left(X\cap B^{c}\right)$$
is sufficient for this because - as an immediate consequence of the
fact that $m$ is an outer measure - we allready have $m\left(X\right)\leq m\left(X\cap B\right)+m\left(X\cap B^{c}\right)$.

So it must be shown that $m\left(X\right)\geq m\left(X\cap A\right)+m\left(X\cap A^{c}\right)$
for each $X\in\wp\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ under the condition $m\left(B\right)=0\wedge A\subseteq B$.

From $X\cap A\subseteq B$ we are allowed to conclude that $m\left(X\cap A\right)=0$
so what remains is proving $m\left(X\right)\geq m\left(X\cap A^{c}\right)$ wich is immediate.